# HTML Tables has a weird bold horizontal line due to border-collapse property

Tags: html, css

***Edit 1:*** The issue seems to be with the border-collapse property of CSS
so it can be fixed by using border-spacing: 0px. But then why is border-collapse causing it? it has something to do with scaling as in if you are zoomed in or out of the window it causes the weird bold lines but in my case, I have the browser set to default zoom as well as the system (windows 11) is also at recommended 125% ( which I always used) scaling. I don't understand what is wrong

[image: Issue as a gif]

Recently I am getting a weird horizontal line after some rows when I try to create an HTML table. I have attached the screenshot. The code is a simple HTML table and simple CSS to add borders nothing fancy. I will attach the code here.

[image: Image attached]

***table.html***

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
        <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
    <?php while($user= mysqli_fetch_array($query)){ ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $user['id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $user['name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $user['phone']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $user['email']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

***style.css***

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Comment: If this is all the code, its not going to replicate the issue. Inspect your HTML in a browser and change the border values

Comment: tried that also. Nothing seems to work

Comment: Could it be that your browser is zoomed in? Try `CTRL + 0` to reset and see if it fixes the issue.

Comment: @DvdRom happening with every browser

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue with the code provided. I only know this issue from scaling. Could it be that you use i high resolution display and have display scaling activated? If not, could you provide more code to reproduce it?

Comment: @DvdRom That's all the code. all in all, I noticed that the bold line happens when I put border-collapse: collapse property? So the issue is basically with scaling. How can if fix this? My browser is at 100% default zoom, the system is 125% recommended scaling with a resolution of 1920 x 1080

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is caused by improper scaling handling of browsers.

If you have a 1px border and `DPI Scaling` set to, for example 150%, the border would technically be 1.5px. Because the browser doesn't use sub-pixel rendering, it alternates between 1px and 2px.

There are multiple ways to deal with it.

---

### **1**. Set the `border-width` to `0.01px`

A quick and dirty workaround, because the Browser will fallback to at least `1px`

---

### **2**. Use `resolution` media queries

Change the border-width to the appropriate decimal per scaling level.

```
@media (min-resolution: 120dpi) {
  table, th, td {
    border-width: 0.75px;
  }
}

@media (min-resolution: 144dpi) {
  table, th, td {
    border-width: 0.666px;
  }
}

@media (min-resolution: 192dpi) {
  table, th, td {
    border-width: 0.5px;
  }
}
```

Here's an overview of the different DPI Scaling Levels and their values

**DPI Scaling Level**

- Smaller 100% (default) = 96 dpi
- Medium 125% = 120 dpi
- Larger 150% = 144 dpi
- Extra Large 200% = 192 dpi

---

### **3**. JavaScript

Change the border-width to the appropriate decimal per scaling level with JavaScript using the `window.devicePixelRatio` variable.

Comment: Yes, it's working and I guess also the solution. But my question is how can I avoid this? I mean where am I wrong? As I have been writing HTML for quite a long time now and this is the first time I am encountering such issue.

Comment: @inc.mak Glad to hear. The only way i can think of to avoid this is to try to file a bug report with the browser vendors.

Comment: Okay, Thankyou for helping out. I marking your response as an answer. Thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

Using DvdRom answer, I fixed this issue with Javascript and CSS variable to get a 1px border-spacing.
Looks like it's working on Firefox, Chrome, Edge, Opera and Brave.

```js
let cssRoot = document.querySelector(':root');
cssRoot.style.setProperty
(
     '--table-border-spacing',
     `${1 / window.devicePixelRatio}px`
);
```

```css
:root {
    --table-border-spacing: 1px;
}

table {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: var(--table-border-spacing);
}
```